# How to install curl in Ubuntu when apt-get doesn't do it right on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, curl

My curl on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS isn't working (it says there's a certificate problem on any https website, but my OS certificates are fine... I can access the same sites just fine in a browser. Even tried exporting the working browser's certificates and curl still doesn't work). Apt-get says curl is up-to-date. Obviously it's not.
So I went to the curl page:
https://curl.se/docs/install.html. It says to use vcpkg. Problem is, vcpkg needs curl!

Here is the log from the failed vcpkg install:

```
-- Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.3.tar.gz -> openssl-3.0.3.tar.gz...
[DEBUG] To include the environment variables in debug output, pass --debug-env
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'binarycaching' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'manifests' = off
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'compilertracking' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'registries' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'versions' unset
[DEBUG] 31607: popen(curl --fail -L https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.3.tar.gz --create-dirs --output /root/rclone/vcpkg/downloads/openssl-3.0.3.tar.gz.31607.part 2
>&1)
[DEBUG] 31607: cmd_execute_and_stream_data() returned 60 after   394329 us
Error: Failed to download from mirror set:
https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.3.tar.gz:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

So this seems like a dead-end. How else can I get curl?

If it helps, here is the `curl` that I have (from `apt-get`)

```
curl --version
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

And system info:

```
uname -a
Linux moxie 4.15.0-142-generic #146~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 09:27:15 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: “…it says there's a certificate problem on any https website, but my OS certificates are fine... I can access the same sites just fine in a browse…” This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319). Whenever I use Curl on the command line I have to add the `-k` option for it to successfully connect to HTTPS sites. Something like `curl -ILk https://www.google.com/` to check the chain of redirects to a website like Google. More on `curl -ILk` [here](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+-ILk). But within scripts — like PHP — built in Curl functions work fine.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 If `curl` and the site are set up properly then `-k` is not needed. That's why e.g. the `vcpkg` script assumes it can use curl without `-k`. But in my case (and yours, apparently), `curl` is not set up properly so I want to reinstall it.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you edit your question to post the output of `curl --version`? I think you have a functional Curl install but something very obvious and simple might be missing?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I've posted the version info at the end of the question.

Comment: Okay, Curl version 7.47 goes back to 2016. What version of Ubuntu is this? So it might be a TLS issue related to this being an old version. I would recommend not compiling from source — too many “X” factors — but instead install Curl from a trusted repo. Something like what is outlined in [these instructions here](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-upgrade-curl-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/).

Comment: FWIW, `uname -a` is more complex output than needed. The output of `lsb_release -a` is clearer. For example, on an Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS system I get this; inline formatting due to this being a comment: `Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal`

Comment: @Giacomo1968. Those instructions seem to want to install a curl that is too new for Ubuntu16. They want libcurl4 which wants libpsl 0.16, but Ubuntu16 can only run libcurl3 and libpsl 0.11.

Comment: Okay, that explains it all: Ubuntu 16.04 is end of life as of just over a year ago. If that is the case, a source code install _might_ be your only hope. But I would recommend seeing if can at least upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 as [explained here](https://yannmjl.medium.com/how-to-manually-update-curl-on-ubuntu-server-899476062ad6). This is the best I can do for now, but hopefully with your post fleshed out and these comments clarifying it, someone will come along who might be able to help you figure out what solid next steps might be. Best of luck!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1368591 note that askubuntu.com is usually a better site for these kinda questions